# Code highlighting problems with prettify in VoltRb

Tags: syntax-highlighting, prettify, voltrb

I've been having some problems getting the JavaScript [prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) library to work on a project in VoltRb. The problem is that the code highlighting seems to work only when an error occurs and the page is reloaded. I think that the problem has something to do with Volt's persistent connection and that part of the problem is the `prettify` script is not finding the elements it needs to find, and any custom themes are also having the same problem.

Here is a simple demo project demonstrating my issue: https://github.com/ylluminarious/code_prettify_volt

How can I get code highlighting working with `prettify` in Volt?

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, `prettify` is not a good solution for code-highlighting in Volt, as it is more geared for static apps. A better solution is [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org) (since it is more geared for dynamic apps), which actually has been incorporated into a [Volt component](https://github.com/voltrb/volt-code_highlight) which works very well for all your highlighting needs.